# Drupal Commerce - Product Variation Type missing Nodes

Tags: commerce

I've installed kickstart 2.0 with the demo data. 
I tried creating my own product variation types and product displays.
I can't see to get my products to display in the same way to the commerce built-in demo products.

I think this is my custom product variation type **seems to be missing the correct "Node: Product list" and "Node: Full Content" options** (Product Variation Type -> Manage Display section)

Please see attachments. 
"Tops" is the built in product variation type delivered with CK 2.0.
"Photos" is a product variation type i created.

Drupal commerce is my first exposure to drupal hence my knowledge of nodes isn't sound, please let me know what I'm missing?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add and remove Displays to your content types by expanding the 'Custom Display Settings' section right under all those fields in the 'Manage display' tab.  It's hard to notice because it's collapsed by default.

You'll probably see a different list than me, because it also depends on the modules you have enabled on your site:

[image]

However, my feeling is that - though I haven't used kickstart and its examples - the differentiation in the look of your content type and theirs also has a lot to do with theming.  That's a big topic, but I'd check to see whether there are templates and css styles that apply to those sample content types that you can copy over to yours...

Comment: Hi Boriana, thanks that fixed it for me. Yes I missed that collapsed section  "Custom Display Settings" which is where I could enable those "nodes".

Comment: Sweet!  I'm so glad this helped.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the new "display modes" to show is the first step to recreating the look / feel of the Kickstart views.

From there, I recommend opening the Commerce Kickstart views and replicating the setup. For instance, when you first activate the "Product List" display, many more fields are visible. You can edit that in the "Manage Display" tab.

Each time you create a new Product type, you will need to repeat this process. It's a bit of a chore, but requires the setup once :)